# Renamed returned JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have the need for modifying JSON returned by a Ruby app.
From my googling it seems that I have to override as_json in my class, but I am not able to get it to work

JSON:

```
"foo_class" =     {
        "created_at" = "2011-03-30T11:45:48Z";            
         #And so forth....
```

I would like to modify foo_class to foo, i.e. the class name it self,and none of the properties.

```
class FooClass < ActiveRecord::Base

def as_json(options={})
json = super(options)
    #How do i modify only the class name in returned json?
    #And leave the properties as is...
    return json
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In rails 3.0.5 you can use option `:root` in `as_json` method in your controller:

```
@foo_classes.as_json(:root => 'foo')
```

You can check it with [this app on github](https://github.com/Imomoi/stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/5496124-renamed-returned-json/test_app), following path `http://localhost:3000/foo_classes.js`